# Nginx tries to load non existent directory

Tags: nginx

When i type mydomain.com/randomfolder or domain.com/somefolder it just loads the index page

my question is there a better way to configure this to redirect the user to an error page rather than just trying to load the directory or process the request?

```
server {
#listen 80 default_server;
#listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;
listen 443 ssl;

root /var/www;
autoindex on;
index index.html index.htm index.php;

server_name mydomain.com;

ssl_certificate    /etc/nginx/ssl/mydomain.com.crt;
ssl_certificate_key    /etc/nginx/ssl/mydomain.com.key;

location / {
    # First attempt to serve request as file, then
    # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;
    # Uncomment to enable naxsi on this location
    # include /etc/nginx/naxsi.rules
}

location /doc/ {
    alias /var/www/;
    autoindex on;
    allow 127.0.0.1;
    allow ::1;
    deny all;
}

location ~ \.php$ {
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    # NOTE: You should have "cgi.fix_pathinfo = 0;" in php.ini
    # With php5-cgi alone:
    #fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
    # With php5-fpm:
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_read_timeout 300;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    include fastcgi.conf;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is normal behavior for the posted configuration.

If you want to change that, the offending directive is:

```
 try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;
```

And, if thy directive offends thee, pluck it out.

The reason this is offensive is because it says to do the following things with *every* http request:

1. first try the request as is
2. then try adding a `/` on the end
3. finally, try fetching `/index.php` instead

You can chop off the 3rd item, or get rid of it entirely.

You can also add a [custom 404 page](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpCoreModule#error_page):

```
error_page 404 /path/to/my/404.html ;
```

but you must get rid of the `/index.php` in the `try_files`, or even the entire line, before requests will fail and only then on failure will the custom 404 display.

Comment: thanks Paul getting rid of the line entirely seemed to be the trick.